# Como saber si una PK esta en otra tabla en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

La consulta es la siguiente.

Tengo una tabla cultura con primary key CulturaID.
Lo que necesito es hacer un procedimiento almacenado, donde elimine un registro de la tabla cultura mediante el ID, pero para poder elimarlo no se tiene que estar referenciando en otra tabla y usando esa id.

Tengo lo siguiente que busca que tabla esta haciendo referencia y cual es la columna.

```
select OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id),
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id)
    from sys.foreign_keys as f
    inner join sys.foreign_key_columns as fc
    on f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
    inner join sys.tables as t
    on t.object_id = fc.referenced_object_id
    where OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = 'Cultura'
```

Pero ¿como hago para eliminar el registro de la tabla Cultura si no se esta usando en alguna otra tabla.?

Comment: Si hiciste correctamente la relación en entre las 2 tablas, y no habilitaste la opción de eliminar en cascada, no debería de permitir eliminar el registro, debido a que otra tabla tiene una dependencia por llave foránea (foreign key o FK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente script borrará el registro solo si no tiene registros relacionados, si está relacionado, en cambio mostrará un mensaje de error indicando las tablas donde tiene registros relacionados.

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(128);
declare @ColumnName nvarchar(128);
declare @sSQL nvarchar(max);
declare @Contador bigint;
declare @ErrorMsg nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @idABuscar bigint = 16;

declare cLlaves cursor for 
    select   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName
           , COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColumnName
     from sys.foreign_keys as f
          inner join sys.foreign_key_columns as fc on f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
          inner join sys.tables as t on t.object_id = fc.referenced_object_id
    where OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = 'Nomenclatura';

open cLlaves;

fetch next from cLlaves into @TableName, @ColumnName;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  set @sSQL = 'select @Contador = count(1) from ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' = ' + cast(@idABuscar as nvarchar);
  exec sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@Contador bigint output', @Contador output;
  if @Contador > 0 
    set @ErrorMsg = @ErrorMsg + ' ' + @TableName;
  fetch next from cLlaves into @TableName, @ColumnName;
end;

if @ErrorMsg = ''
  delete from Nomenclatura where idNomenclatura = @idABuscar;
else
begin
  set @ErrorMsg = 'No se puede eliminar porque tiene registros asociados en las siguientes tablas: ' + @ErrorMsg;
  raiserror(@ErrorMsg, 16, 1);
end;
close cLlaves;
deallocate cLlaves;
```

Dicho esto, debieras configurar tu integridad referencial, para que hacer algo como esto no sea necesario. De hecho, ya tienes declaradas llaves foráneas entre las tablas, de otra forma el query no devolvería filas. Para cada llave foránea puedes indicar una regla de borrado. Si es cascada, al borrar el registro maestro, se borrarán los detalles. En cambio, si la regla es bloquear, al haber registros relacionados, el motor mismo generará un mensaje de error apropiado.

Por otro lado, el *script* tiene la limitante que solo trabaja con llaves foráneas *simples*, es decir, con un solo campo de relación. No funcionará correctamente si hay una llave compuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda me sirvio. Tengo que la regla es bloquear el borrado del registro si hay registro relacionados pero es un ejercicio que me tenia que hacerlo de esa forma, osea buscar si estaba relacionada con una tabla y verificar que no se use en esa otra tabla.